# Why can't I properly map nested query on Laravel? "Call to a member function map() on null" shown as error

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Really could not get the desired data after map function. I was looking to get credit, date from saving_details and the just saving_bill_number from saving_bills through relation, but now looks like I am stucked in this fatal problem. Call to member function on map shown ad fatal error. Your help would be appreciated.

This is the relation:

```
public function savingBill()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SavingBill::class);
}
```

Here is my controller logic:

```
$savingDetails = SavingDetail::where('date', $request->date)
    ->with('savingBill')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($savingDetail) {
        return [
            'credit' => $savingDetail->credit,
            'date' => $savingDetail->date,
            'saving_bill' => $savingDetail
                ->saving_bill
                ->map(function ($inner) {
                    return [
                        'saving_bill_number' => $inner->saving_bill_number
                    ];
                }) // If I put an semicolon here, IDK why error would be shown, hope nothing with the semicolon
        ];
    });
```

[This is the error that I'm getting.Please check the image for the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joIZa.png)

[I need to filter above mentioned data from here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGueo.png)

Comment: Please add all error messages, along with your debugging attempts, to the question by editing it

Comment: You probably have a records in db, which has empty relations based on the error image.
you can try to put `try catch` block code inside map to understand where it's failing and what's the case.

Comment: Sir, I've got only 3 entries in db at the moment and there is no any null  entries between both of the tables. But I've set that saving_bill_id as a  nullable in db. Would that will be an issue? And How am I tried to use Try Catch inside map, but it gave unreacheable statement as an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which of these `map()` actually throws the error but I guess it's the second one that iterates through the `saving_bill` relation.
You said in the comments that `saving_bill_id` can be null. If that's the case the relation will also be null and there is no Collection providing the `map()` method.

Check for null before you assume that this variable is always filled:

```
$savingDetails = SavingDetail::where('date', $request->date)
    ->with('savingBill')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($savingDetail) {
        return [
            'credit' => $savingDetail->credit,
            'date' => $savingDetail->date,
            'saving_bill' => $savingDetail->saving_bill
                ? $savingDetail
                    ->saving_bill
                    ->map(function ($inner) {
                        return [
                            'saving_bill_number' => $inner->saving_bill_number
                        ];
                    })
                : null,
        ];
    });
```